# Only first object in list being deserialized

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I'm having trouble with deserializing a list of objects. For some reason only the first object in the serialized list is returned from the load method. I've looked at numerous questions that seem related, but haven't been able to find a solution to my specific problem. I think it may have something to do with the private backing collection I'm using? Any help would be appreciated. (class names and methods have been made generic)

Here's my deserialization method:

```
    public static ObjectList LoadLibrary()
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream loadStream;
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "ObjectList.bin");
        ObjectList lib = null;

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            lib = new ObjectList();
            return lib;
        }

        try
        {
            using (loadStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                lib = (ObjectList)formatter.Deserialize(loadStream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Object list could not be loaded. Error: \n" + e);
        }
        return lib;
    }
```

Here's my ObjectList class;

```
[Serializable]
public class ObjectList: IEnumerable<Obj>
{
    #region Construction
    /// <summary>
    /// Contracts Test Case Library Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ObjectList() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Private backing collection
    /// </summary>
    private List<Obj> _objectList = new List<Obj>();
    #endregion
```

And for good measure, here's my Obj class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Obj
{
    #region Constructors
    public Obj(string Name, string Description)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Description = Description;
    }

    public Obj() { }
    #endregion
```

Comment: nevermind... I realized that it was an issue with my save method. I had was using filemode append when that wasnt appropriate.